# greedy matches in javacc

Tags: javacc

Is it possible to optionally make javacc match greedily some of the tokens?

I'm trying to have an entity defined like this:

```
<CURLED:     "{" (<CHAR>)+ "}">
```

What I would like to have is that sequences:

```
a. {HELLO}
b. {HELLO} {WORLD}
c. {HELLO} {OUR} {WORLD}
```

are parsed correctly and javacc would consume tokens in curly brackets individually.

By default, javacc tries to make the longest match possible such that cases b and c end up being parsed like:

```
b. HELLO} {WORLD
c. HELLO} {OUR} {WORLD
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem by not allowing "{" character to occur in the CURLED token definition. This exclusion is done with ~["{"].

Comment: If you want to allow the "{" character, you can use lexical states. Your problem is then very similar to the problem of matching C style comments.  E.g. /*/**/ is a valid comment, whereas /**//**/ is two comments. See the JavaCC FAQ for discussion.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell Thanks for your response! The reason I didn't go for states (even though started reading how to implement them) was that I don't allow nesting of '{','}' inside a pair of '{}' (taking your analogy with C style comments).

Comment: Then `"{" (~["{"])+ "}"` is the way to go.

Comment: That's exactly how I did it. Thanks!

Comment: On second thought, shouldn't it be `"{" (~["{", "}"])+ "}"`?

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell can't check it right now, but will it ever finish matching from the first "{" to its closing pair, if the latter is excluded? Can you explain, please?

Comment: Consider remaining input of `{a} } {b}`. The first expression `"{" (~["{"])+ "}"` will match the whole thing.  The second expression `"{" (~["{", "}"])+ "}"` will match `{a}`.  It may be an error to have a '}` between CURLED tokens; but then the first expression will not let the parser report the error while the second will.